Ubuntu 24.04 with Private Public IP not able to connect with external computers via Ping
Currently, I am facing an issue while trying to set up a server on my Ubuntu PC.
It seems like the current PC is located in NAT and has only a private IP address ( 192.168.x.x ).
What I want to do, is to have it a public IP address and let other clients connect to my server.
Yesterday, I got a new Business Modem with a Public Static IP a member of Spectrum Business Internet set up…but I don't  know how to set it up so my PC can be connected with other clients all over the world.
My PC has Ubuntu 24.04 installed on it and I have GNOME Desktop UI built into it.
My need is to make my PC discoverable by “Ping” command on other client's PC’s anywhere in the world…
Any assistance is appreciated :-)

Sounds like a question for whom ever supplied the modem.

Is this the only PC connected to this private network? This seems like a networking question rather than an Ubuntu related question. Are you familiar with network Address Translation (NAT)? Which ports will your server user to communicate with the outside world? Edit your question and add the answers to these clarifying questions.

David - Was thinking that as well, just...technical support can sometimes be not so supportive, you know? lol
User68186 - I actually did mention in the original that it is located in a NAT.  I had read some things about "Port Forwarding" does that sound like a possible solution?
And thank you both! :-)

You will need to use the modem configuration software to forward whichever ports you plan to use to your PC. This doesn't actually have anything to do with Ubuntu, yet.

You need to setup your Private network etc before you expose your personal PC or a server to the harshness that is the internet.  A misconfiguration can cause issues with nefarious people.

@HacimRetnuh Is the private IP address of your Ubuntu server static or dynamically assigned by your router/modem? Did you use your router/modem to assign (reserve) a specific IP address for the Ubuntu server? Edit your question and add the information we ask for inside the question. Then alert the person who asked for this clarification with a comment starting with @<userID> as I have done in this comment.

You may use the "DMZ" feature of the router if it is available in your router to fully expose your Ubuntu server to the outside world. This is a very dangerous thing to do.  Your Ubuntu server may be taken over by hackers within minutes of doing this.

Like other said in your comment's you are getting deep into networking.  There are many possible solutions, but each will require some knowledge in both linux networking and the specifics of your needs.
It sounds like your Business Modem is also a router, so Spectrum is the place to look for support for your setup.  Then you will want to setup rules for specific ports to forward to your Linux computer.  However whatever port that is exposed to the outside word is a potential vector for someone to take control of your computer.  So you will want good security measures in place as well, that blocks know bad actors or if you are able, only allows connections from specific computers.
Without working on your system, and knowing your exact needs for the customer access, it's hard to say.  If you only need Ping.  That's usually a setting in the router.  Where it can respond to "Ping" requests or not.
